# Autofocus on reactstrap alerts using react functional component

Tags: reactjs, alert, react-hooks, reactstrap

I am using react hooks for my frontend designs and while creating a register form I have used various validations and I am depicting errors using reactstrap warning alerts.
And things are working fine but when focus is not implemented on these alers means when my page shows any of alert, it doesn't focus on that automatically.

I have tried basic codes for autofocus/ autoFocus or Focus() but nothing is working as per need.
My alert code look as shown below:

```
  {
        showAlreadyRegisteredAlert?
        <Alert variant="warning" onClose={() => setShowAlreadyRegisteredAlert(false)} dismissible>
        <p className="mb-0">
        {content}
        </p>
      </Alert>
        :null
      }
```

I am just writing these alert codes in between my form inputs and whenever I need to call any of them I simply setValue for the commponent and alert box is called but still it lacks autofocus.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to focus on the alert?

Comment: I have designed a registration form and im using these alerts to show validation messages... Therefore, I want to get page focus on particular alert message.

Comment: Could you show a working example on codepen or something?

Comment: Sorry, I can show you working example. But its just simple thing to understand. I have desgined a registeration form For ex. with fields: Username, password, confirm password only and now on submit I am validating this form at server end and if password and confirm password dosen't match then it send http status with message and then I am showing that massage as alert to the user. I am able to show the alerts but when this alert apppears i want focus of my page on that alert only. That's all is remaining focus on particular alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the desired solution as I wanted my page should automatically focused on appearing alert boxes. I searched react-hooks official documention and get to know that we can use "useRef" for the purpose and below is my code for better understanding and clarification:

First: import useRef from react.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from "react";
```

Second: create const with desired name using useRef as null.

```
const inputUser = useRef(null);
```

Third: set focus on your ref const after alert.

```
setShowAlreadyRegisteredAlert(true);
inputUser.current.focus();
```

Fourth: pass ref as const which you defined in step 2 inside your input field.

```
    ref= {inputUser}
```